# Can I configure postgres to listen on a VIP?

Tags: linux, postgresql, networking, virtual-ip-address

I would like to be able to configure postgres to listen on specific interfaces, rather than '*', but one of them is virtual IP (VIP).

If I configure listen_addresses in postgresql.conf with the IP addresses of the interfaces, it works properly except for the VIP - postgres does not actually listen on the VIP.

However, if I configure listen_addresses to listen on '*', then when the VIP becomes active on the local machine, postgres picks it up and listens on that interface as expected.

Is there some option I am overlooking, maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "virtual IP"? If the virtual IP up when the postgresql service is started?

Comment: Assuming this is Linux, you may need to set `net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind` so PostgreSQL can bind to the VIP whether or not it's active at startup.

Comment: @redneb, no, the VIP is not up when postgres is started.  We have another process that manages the VIPs, and it only assigns the VIP when postgres is running and active!

Comment: @mwp, thanks!  That did it for me.  Post it as an answer and I will mark it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Happy to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codifying my (apparently helpful) answer from the comments:

Assuming this is Linux, you may need to set `net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind` so PostgreSQL can bind to the VIP whether or not it's active at startup.

Comment: For more information, see here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Load_Balancer_Administration/s1-initial-setup-forwarding-VSA.html